# graph api 1.0 create event team calendar access denied

Tags: azure, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to create a scheduled meeting in teams using the Microsoft.Graph.Client SDK.
Environment .NET Core 3.1.

When we call functions that update or read the events we get always the same error:

Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:...

the api called is:

POST /groups/{id}/events

if we try also with the update of a manually created event we get the some error.

the api called is:

PATCH /groups/{id}/events/{id}

in azure we granted some permission.

I tried both delegated and application authentication.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Which permission you granted, it should be Calendar.ReadWrite granted by admin. Please make sure you have permission included in access_token roles. You can check that at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

Answer (score 0):

according to microsoft docs, the permission Delegated (work or school account) `Group.ReadWrite.All` is required:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events

perhaps you could run your code as team owner.

or you could try it with this approach:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings
```

https://myteamsday.com/2019/09/10/using-graph-api-to-create-a-instant-meeting-in-teams/